# Why does the printing of this float number result in the wrong answer in c

Tags: c

I'm learning c and I wasn't able to find an answer through google (maybe I'm using bad keywords)

Anyways this is a simple program to obtain the average grade of students in 2 subjects:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int grades[2][2] = {{90, 78}, {92, 83}};
    float avg1, avg2;
    avg1 = ( grades[1][1] + grades[2][1] ) / 2;
    avg2 = ( grades[2][1] + grades[2][2] ) / 2;
    printf("Average 1 is: %d \n", avg1);
    printf("Average 1 is: %f", avg1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting an answer of 91.

%d gives me: 250732472

%f gives me: 16424.000000

Why does this happen? I found a solution online that uses int data type for the grades array and float for the averages and their solution worked.

Comment: Hello, and welcome.  Please be sure to include complete code.  Your code is missing the value for the format in `printf`, which suggests it's not actually the code you're running.

Comment: @DanielFarrell he is probably running the code he posted. The reason why he sees such random values is that, since the expected format is missing, printf tries to print some random info in the stack. So OP is probably ignoring warnings too.

Comment: Also, this invokes undefined behavior by using an index of 2 when  the array size is 2. Only indices 0 and 1 are valid.

Comment: @FredK that was the error i was having. I fixed it and received the right answer. I wasn't getting any warning messages so I didn't realize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're not printing anything because there's an argument missing in each of your `printf` calls - the value that matches each format specifier.

Now, in case your code looked like this,

```
avg1 = ( grades[1][1] + grades[2][1] ) / 2;
avg2 = ( grades[2][1] + grades[2][2] ) / 2;
printf("Average 1 is: %d\n", avg1);
printf("Average 2 is: %f\n", avg2);
```

then you're dealing with undefined behavior, which is why your output looks funky. That is because, in your first `printf` call, you're using `%d` - which is the format specifier for integers. If you want to print a floating point variable, be it 32 (`float`) or 64(`double`) bits long, you should use the specifier `%f`.

There is yet another problem with your code that causes undefined behavior: `grades` is 2 elements long, so the `[2]` index is out of bounds.

Comment: Given `float avg1;`, the call `printf("Average 1 is: %d\n", avg1);` is undefined behavior.  You can not use `%d` to print a `float`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I should have added it in there, thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: Both this and the original code access the array out of bounds.  Indices should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 2.

Comment: @Clifford Didn't even notice the array access thing. I'll edit accordingly - thanks!

Comment: @SaucyGoat that is the code I had in my file, I have edited the original question to add the missing parameters. Also the error was the out of bounds index. After I fixed that I got the right answers. Surprisingly I didn't get any error messages when running the code with that error.

Comment: @uconnboi Be sure to compile with flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra` if you're using `gcc` :)